# Node.js and Php deployment

Tags: node.js

I have experience with Php from school. I know that if you want to build a website in php you simply need an host and write page with the .php extension.
You might need a database for crud operations of course.

Now I was trying to shift from php  to node. I just can't understand how node works. It's probably my brain that can't reach the ha ah moment.

So first of all, let's say I want to create a website with login, sign up, different pages etc.. And I want to use node as server side language. In php you just needed to write  in the actual page, upload on the server and it dose what you ask..

How this is possible in node.js? Pages are in javascript and javascript is editable from the browser becouse is clientside. So how do i write node and where? I can't understand how does it work...

How to chose a good host for node? I remember websites like Aruba hosting that just gave me space to upload my php pages. How does it work for node? Are there particular host?

Sorry guys I know it is maybe a dumb question. But I need to get out of this limbo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start by splitting up your questions:

> So first of all, let's say I want to create a website with login, sign up, different pages etc.. And I want to use node as server side language. In php you just needed to write in the actual page, upload on the server and it dose what you ask..

First we have to understand WHY PHP works like that. According to [TechTerms](https://techterms.com/definition/php):

> PHP Stands for "Hypertext Preprocessor." PHP is an HTML-embedded Web
>   scripting language. This means PHP code can be inserted into the HTML
>   of a Web page. When a PHP page is accessed, the PHP code is read or
>   "parsed" by the server the page resides on. The output from the PHP
>   functions on the page are typically returned as HTML code, which can
>   be read by the browser. Because the PHP code is transformed into HTML
>   before the page is loaded, users cannot view the PHP code on a page.

This of course, is the original purpose(and still is) of PHP, embedding server-side code in HTML without returning the source and only the intended output, thus it's name Hypertext **Pre**processor.
The most classical example, is trying to return a custom message inside an HTML element:

```php
<html>
    <body>
        <div> Hey <b><?php echo $username ?></b>, how are you today? </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output would look something like this:

> Hey **RavenMask**, how are you today?

This is PHP. There are of course, several frameworks available that do change the way you interact with PHP, like the MVC model that Laravel uses.

But now lets move on to **NodeJS**.
Node is very different from PHP, but still share equal concepts, like both being interpreted, and i believe this is where your confusion started, you probably thought that the code bellow was equivalent of PHP:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div> Hey
    <script>
      document.write(`<b>RavenMask</b>`)
    </script>, how are you today? </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And in some ways, it is, for client side.
NodeJS is a server-side runtime enviroment, in a more simple-to-understand comparison, NodeJS works exactly like C, Java or C++(Node does not need a compiler like GCC thought, it works using a JIT compiler, but that's for another question).
While PHP is a language designed from the ground to run over a webserver and become easily embeeded on HTML, Node on the other hand is designed more like a traditional language, so, for achieving a result like PHP, a LOT of steps are required, just like you would need with C, C++, Java and any other language.

In Node, to achieve what PHP does, you would need:

1. Creating an HTTP Server.
2. Creating an templating engine to mimic what PHP does inside HTML.

Luckily for us, all those steps have been already implemented in battle tested modules(and even in the native NodeJS default library!), so, the most barebones example that you can get is this:

```
const http = require('http')

// Here you're creating the HTTP server, like Apache
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const username = 'RavenMask'

  // Abuse templating strings!
  // Respose.end means: Give this back to the client and end the cicle of the request
  response.end(`
    <html>
        <body>
            <div> Hey <b>${username}</b>, how are you today? </div>
        </body>
    </html>
  `)
})

// Here is where you create the event loop for the HTTP server
server.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening`)
})
```

Go on, save this file as index.js and on your terminal type:

```
node index.js
```

Then go to localhost:3000 on your browser and voilá!
[image: Output example on NodeJS]

This of course, is NOT production ready, so be careful.

To wrap it up, if you're still interested in Node, the steps you need to take are:

1. Understand how Node works, including its architecture and the most important, the *event loop*.
2. Use and abuse frameworks and modules. The example i gave you above, if you tried to expand it, would cause a lot of suffering and pain due the way it's designed, but it's fine so you can learn. Using frameworks and modules, you get battle-tested, community contributed code that can make your life easier, safer and production-ready, one good example, is creating an HTTP server with the [Fastify Framework](https://www.fastify.io/).
3. Don't give up: Learning a different language sure is hard, but can give you a lot of opportunities on the market and you can learn a LOT from looking things from a different angle, you usually end up acknowledging mistakes you do on another languages by looking on how things work from another.

Comment: That's an amazing answer! I'm so happy as I got finally something. Just another questions, you show me that you used your terminal to I think compile? the index.js. How does it work if I want to host my website online, in a hosting service there is not a terminal. I mean in php I never used the terminal... I think that is what confuse me.

Comment: @RavenMask Far as i'm concerned, every hosting service offers access to the terminal using SSH, if they don't, they offer several ways of running NodeJS scripts(Amazon Lambda for example) without the terminal. If by some reason the service does not offer access to running any kind of command, then you're out of luck, what service do you have in mind? As for the 'compile part', read here: https://hashnode.com/post/is-nodejs-compiled-or-interpreted-language-cijylh0ed00keco5318e1em8p - The way Node works under the sheets is very complex and i suggest further reading.